# Did my question deserve to get closed? Is there any way to still get the answers I need?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, vote-to-reopen

The following question of mine has been closed:

[Is JBoss just plain awful at reporting errors? Or is there another log file? Or is this just my fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792971/is-jboss-just-plain-awful-at-reporting-errors-or-is-there-another-log-file-or)

I feel that it was unfairly closed! However, I will be the first to admit that the title wasn't the best and can kind of understand what [casperOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) meant when they said that the ultimate question wasn't clear - but give me a chance...? I put a considerable amount of time laying out the question and there clearly questions there that I wanted answers to:

- From the title: Or is there another log file?
- Are there any more files anywhere?!
- Further near the bottom] Is this worth investigating?

And, OK, not a question but hopefully clear enough that I want some input / suggestions:

- Any ideas / suggestions welcome!

Is there any way I can get this re-opened? And fair enough if a little re-wording would be required first...but give me a chance..? This problem has been driving me crazy for a few days and am running out of ideas!

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: tl;dr but I will say that starting a post with "Getting a little p*ssed off with JBoss" doesn't set a good tone for the rest of the post, and pushes it into the "not constructive" area.

Comment: From the votes down...is my question that awful? Please some comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Closure on SO is not permanent. If you make it a proper question, it can reopened via votes.

Comment: Not my DV, but read here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @Bart - thanks for point me to that - hadn't realised.

Comment: That's a lot of question to chew through.  Are you certain that you can't pare it down further, or split it up into several smaller questions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, it's clear you have an issue somewhere, but:

> Is JBoss just plain awful at reporting errors? Or is there another log file? Or is this just my fault?

Sets spidey-senses tingling for this line of the [don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) section in the faq FAQ:

> it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Then the question begins:

> Getting a little p*ssed off with JBoss...

and later

> There are no 'previous startup errors'...thanks JBoss...not really that helpful?

which pretty much nails it, I think.

---

I realise programming is sometimes frustrating and 90 ft stack traces so common to frameworks are about as clear as mud, but you can only do what experienced devs do - work through the problem until you find the answer(1). If you're stuck, you can ask on Stack Overflow, but remember to include all the relevant information. For example, what is `EM.jar`? What is the remote vs local configuration? I'd do away with the stack traces and simply report the relevant outcome - `ClassNotFoundException`. I'd also agree its not fully clear what you're trying to achieve; something that may be worth clarifying.

Times like these it's always worth linking to Jon Skeet's [how to ask](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) guidance. I wouldn't say you're *that* far off. If I were you I'd edit the question taking into account that guidance and flag it for re-opening. After all, question closure *is not permanent* and *this is the point of it* - to improve questions.

1) this may mean putting in a fair amount of research effort, either by searching or asking on Stack Overflow for any prerequisite questions. It depends on the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input and I do completely agree with most of your answer (when I wrote the question I think it'd be fair to say I was just a little frustrated with JBoss!)...as regards to the content/details of the question, I would hope something like what is the EM.war would be self explanatory. In addition, the ClassNotFoundException is potentially not the exception I am looking for since that's starting up without some configuration files that I assume are needed, but nevertheless - thanks again. Hopefully it'll get re-opened now that I have made some changes :)